# Not sending mails (phpmailer), on windows, with attachements

Tags: php, windows, localhost, sendmail, phpmailer

I would like ton send, simply, a mail with attachements (with a form), on windows.
I'm testing on localhost. All is allright, but phpmailer don't add the attachements, and the mail sending is blank...

Here my code :

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->SetFrom('contact@blabla.fr', 'H');
$mail->AddReplyTo("contact@blabla.fr",'H');         
$mail->AddAddress('contact@blabla.fr', "H"); 

if (isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES)>0) {                   
    foreach ($_FILES as $form) {
        if ($form['error']==0) {
            //$source = str_replace('\\','\\\\',$form["tmp_name"]);
            $source = $form["tmp_name"];
            $name = $form["name"];
            if (!$mail->AddAttachment($source,$name)) {
                echo "ERREUR D'ATTACHEMENT !! : "; var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo);
           }
        }
    }
}                   

$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; 

$subject = "...";
$message = ' ...' ;


$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

if($mail->Send()) {
    $back    = array('response'=>1, 'data'=>'1');
} else {
    $errors = $mail->ErrorInfo;
    $back    = array('response'=>0, 'errors'=>$errors, 'data'=>0);
}
```

I've no error durong the process to add the attachement... bt the mail is blank, with no file attached :(

Thanx,
Fabrice

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the mail function will work on localhost, unless you have setup a mail server.

so the first question would be... do you have a mail server or
then if not.. you will need to deploy to a server with the mail setup (ie a web hosting company)